# Laravel + MySQL - Storing Eloquent namespaces

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I was given this project to work on with absolutely no documentation or contact developer. I noticed in the database dump that they are storing what looks like PHP Namespaces for Eloquent models in a couple tables. For example an address table has a string column named "object_type" with the value always being "App\Entities\Client". I searched through the whole project for the PHP code that would use this value. Hopefully to give me insight to it's purpose. Not to my surprise, the project never uses this value. I just see it hard-coding these values upon insert into the DB.

**My question is**, is this some sort of Database and/or ORM modeling design practice? If so, could you explain how this could be used in a simple practical sense?

Maybe this was some concept the developer had and it never evolved. It's interesting idea but, the idea of joining through MySQL on a string conditional sounds like torture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like Laravel [polymorphic relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations):

> **Custom Polymorphic Types.**
>   By default, Laravel will use the fully qualified class name to store the type of the related model.

And, yes, this is a valid modeling technique, though purists rightly [argue](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/modeling-polymorphic-associations-in-a-relational-database) this technique abuses normal form.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the developers where thinking.

But imagining we are in a forum with thread and replies to each thread. We maybe want to have a **Favourites** table where we can save replies and threads.

A way to do it would be to have a column in the *favourites* table called "object_type" (just to use the same term you have in your case) and then when we save an object into the database with eloquent we can use:

```
$favourite->object_type = get_class($thread); //or get_class($reply) in case we want a reply
$favourite->save();
```

This way will save the namespace of that class into the database. But laravel will recognise it when we get it from the database.

Hope this cold be helpful.